# Name/variable input and listing

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that allows the user to say, input (orange/apple/banana/etc), then the quantity they want to purchase, and the program will calculate the total. However, after trying Strings (Can't multiply them) and a few other options, I'm stuck. I've intensively browsed this forum along with countless guides, to no avail. 
The IF statement I inserted was simply a last ditch random attempt to make it work, of course, it crashed and burned. This is all basic stuff I'm sure, but I'm quite new to this. 
I would also like to display a list to choose from, perhaps something like
Oranges: Qnty: (Box here)
Apples: Qnty: (Box here)
Bananas: Qnty: (Box here)
Etc
But I'd really settle for help as how to allow the user to input a word, orange, and it is assigned the value I have preset so I can multiply it by the quantity. 
All help is appreciated, criticism too of course, to you know, a reasonable extent...
Here's my code.

```
/* Name 1, x0000
* Name 2, x0001
* Name 3, x0003
*/
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SD_CA_W3_TEST1
{
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
double nameOfItem1, nameOfItem2, nameofItem3;
double quantityItem1, quantityItem2, quantityItem3;
final double apple = 0.30;
final double orange = 0.45;
final double strawberry = 2.30;
final double potato = 3.25;
final double turnip = 0.70;
final double carrot =  1.25;
double totalCost;
String strNameOfItem1;


System.out.println(" \t \t What would you like to buy today?");
System.out.print("Please choose from our fine selection of: oranges, strawberries, potatoes, turnips, and carrots. \n" );

System.out.print("Enter name of product ");
nameOfItem1 = in.nextDouble();
nameOfItem1 = If = nameOfItem1 (apple, orange, strawberry, potato, turnip, carrot);
System.out.print("Please enter a quantity to purchase");
quantityItem1 = in.nextDouble();

totalCost = quantityItem1 * strNameOfItem1;

System.out.print("The total cost of your purchase is: " +totalCost );
}
}
```

Comment: You can parse a String into many different `Number` types. Check out `Double.parseDouble()` and `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: Lot of compiler error. Please organize the code.

Comment: How you multiply with string? Look, `totalCost = quantityItem1 * strNameOfItem1`;

Comment: I tried the parsing method a lot, just did it now and got:               2 errors found:
Error: The method parseDouble(java.lang.String) in the type java.lang.Double is not applicable for the arguments (double)

Comment: Sorry about compiler errors, I'm getting none atm. Regards to your comment, Masud, Error: The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) double, java.lang.String

Comment: You could use a Map to store the names of the products along with their price. You could then ask the user for a product (I think there's a method called 'next' in the Scanner) and a quantity (using nextInt unless you 'shop' allows users to buy fractions of products) and then based on the product mappings, lookup the price and multiply. Note that the values you are storing in a Map are in the wrapper type (e.g. Integer for int).

Comment: Interesting approach, @rethab, not one I've found yet. Would you be so kind as to attach some sample code? Perhaps to suit the situation, but general code will work. Thanks for the response, it's new to me and seems promising.

Comment: Map<String, Double> products = new HashMap<String, Double>(); products.push("apple", 1.5); products.get(user_input);

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking complete noob questions @rethab, I have a feeling I am...Error: Map cannot be resolved to a type. Do I need to import a packet for it or am I just special?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a HashMap. Here's a good tutorial:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/hashmap_get.htm

```
HashMap food = new HashMap();
food.put("Apple", 0.30);
food.put("Orange", 0.45);
...
```

then use

```
food.get("Apple");
```

to give you the price.

the grand total would be something like:

```
double quantity = 4.0;    
double total = food.get("apple") * quantity;
```

Comment: I have a feeling if I used this, then the figures I used would mess up quantity. Say someone orders #2 which is say, oranges. Then quantity input, they order 1 item, would that correspond to apple or the value 1?

Comment: I also can't resolve HashMap to a type, do I need to import anything for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try using enums,

```
class Test{

    public enum Fruits{
        apple(0.30), orange(0.45), strawberry(2.30), potato(3.25);

        private final double value;

        Fruits(double value1){
            value = value1;    
        }

        public double getValue(){
            return value;    
        }
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        int quantity = 0;            
        // Read your value here and assign it to quantity

        System.out.println(Fruits.apple.getValue()*quantity);

    }

}
```

Comment: Tried this just now. Can't wrap my head around a way to have users input the values. Terribly sorry, but could you elaborate on the code? I'm bloody useless and quite frustrated after hours on this.

Comment: @AndyFitzmaurice Frustration will lead you no where. Calm down and think about the approach. Ravi has given the solution. I wanted you to think and try the solution, so just presented the idea of enums.

Comment: Yeah well to be honest I'm abusing pub wifi just to be on here, and I'm a few drinks in. That's no problem, and I don't mind working on solutions but I'm so new to this, and you're all posting content I've never seen that it's just a bit hard to work through it. I'm ankle deep in this and still not seeing a lot of answers. I am trying. And I appreciate all help.

Answer (score 0):

`Enum` seems to be a good choice here. It would help you map your item names to the price easily instead of creating several `double` variables.

```
private enum Items {
    APPLE(0.30), ORANGE(0.45), STRAWBERRY(2.30),
    POTATO(3.25), TURNIP(0.70), CARROT(1.25);

    double price;

    Items(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Use `Scanner#next()` to read in `String` and use `Enum.valueOf()` to validate and convert user input into one of your `Item`s.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("What would you like to buy today?");
System.out.println("Please choose from our fine selection of: " +
        "Orange, Strawberry, Potato, Turnip, and Carrot.");
System.out.print("Enter name of product: ");

String nameOfItem = in.next();
Items item;
try {
    // Validate Item
    item = Items.valueOf(nameOfItem.toUpperCase());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("No such item exists in catalog. Exiting..");
    return;
}

System.out.print("Please enter a quantity to purchase: ");
int quantity;
try {
    quantity = in.nextInt();
    if (!(quantity > 0)) { // Validate quantity
        throw new Exception();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Invalid quantity specified. Exiting..");
    return;
}

double totalCost = quantity * item.getPrice();
System.out.printf("The total cost of your purchase is: %.2f", totalCost);
```

***Output** :*

```
What would you like to buy today?
Please choose from our fine selection of: Orange, Strawberry, Potato, Turnip, and Carrot.
Enter name of product: Strawberry
Please enter a quantity to purchase:3
The total cost of your purchase is: 6.90
```

Comment: Looks fantastic, honestly, this is a nice response. I'm hitting a few problems and I'm sorry if they're silly ones I should be able to resolve, but if I figure this out now I'll never forget this. 5 errors found:
Error: Illegal modifier for the enum Items; only public is permitted
Error: Scanner cannot be resolved to a type
Error: Scanner cannot be resolved to a type
Error: This method must return a result of type double
Error: This method must return a result of type double

Comment: Ok fixed a bit, now I'm stuck. 3 errors found:
Error: Illegal modifier for the enum Items; only public is permitted
Error: This method must return a result of type double
Error: This method must return a result of type double

Comment: `Enum` declaration goes inside the `class` but outside the `main()` method. The rest of the code constitutes the complete `main()` method.

Comment: Ok I'm after trying about 10 different variations and keep hitting a dozen odd errors. I don't think I can do it.

Comment: Here's the complete class file: http://pastebin.com/E1CaWj4w Rename the `class` or change the file name to `Test.java`. Runs fine. I tested on JDK 1.6.

Comment: Thank you so much. If it's any consolation for basically writing the code for me, it's a small portion of a much larger project. I will look over this a lot to learn where I can improve, which is everywhere in fairness. This is much appreciated :D.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point. You can refer to it as a reference implementation. Please, do consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the most helpful answer.